# sudo aptitude full-upgrade = 420 conflicts

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, aptitude

I think the following will explain my concern for not wanting to choose `Y`.

```
oshirowanen@desktop:~$ sudo aptitude full-upgrade
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libavcodec53{a} libavutil51{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libavdevice53 libavformat53 libpostproc52 libproxy1 libproxy1:i386 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager 
  libswscale2 python-libproxy 
9 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,804 kB of archives. After unpacking 7,233 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavutil-extra-51 : Conflicts: libavutil51 but 4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed.
 libavcodec-extra-53 : Conflicts: libavcodec53 but 4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed.
open: 418; closed: 3160; defer: 214; conflict: 420                                                                                     oThe following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Remove the following packages:                                                                                           
1)       bluez-alsa:i386                                                                                                        
2)       frei0r-plugins                                                                                                         
3)       glib-networking:i386                                                                                                   
4)       google-earth-stable                                                                                                    
5)       gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg                                                                                                   
6)       gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse                                                                                   
7)       gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386                                                                                        
8)       gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386                                                                                        
9)       gstreamer0.10-x:i386                                                                                                   
10)      gtk2-engines:i386                                                                                                      
11)      gtk2-engines-murrine:i386                                                                                              

( and many more only deleted due to limited characters allowed in question )                                                                                            

247)     melt                                                                                                                   
248)     odbcinst1debian2:i386                                                                                                  
249)     openshot                                                                                                               
250)     python-mlt3                                                                                                            
251)     vlc                                                                                                                    
252)     vlc-nox                                                                                                                
253)     vlc-plugin-notify                                                                                                      
254)     vlc-plugin-pulse                                                                                                       
255)     xaw3dg:i386                                                                                                            
256)     zlib1g:i386                                                                                                            

       Keep the following packages at their current version:                                                                    
257)     libavcodec53 [Not Installed]                                                                                           
258)     libavutil51 [Not Installed]                                                                                            

       Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                                                             
259)     ubuntu-restricted-addons recommends gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg                                                               
260)     ubuntu-restricted-extras recommends gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse                                               
261)     libcanberra-gtk0:i386 recommends libcanberra-gtk-module:i386                                                           
262)     libncurses5:i386 recommends libgpm2:i386                                                                               
263)     libncursesw5:i386 recommends libgpm2:i386                                                                              
264)     libslang2:i386 recommends libpng12-0:i386                                                                              
265)     libvisual-0.4-0:i386 recommends libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386                                                             
266)     libgphoto2-2:i386 recommends udev:i386 (>= 0.175)                                                                      
267)     libgphoto2-2:i386 recommends libgphoto2-l10n:i386 (>= 2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2)                                               
268)     libqt4-dbus:i386 recommends qdbus:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3)                                                          
269)     libqt4-sql:i386 recommends libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 | libqt4-sql-odbc:i386 | libqt4-sql-psql:i386 | libqt4-sql-sqlite:i386


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --full-resolver
```

The **--full-resolver** flag should solve your issue.